# How do I tell git to stop showing a file in git status until it's modified again?

Tags: git

Sometimes I go into files and just clean up a little, removing uneeded spaces and whatnot. Then of course since the file is changed, when I run `git status` it shows up in the list:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
modified:   myfile.js
```

Is there a way to get git to stop thinking there's been a change, at least until I change it again (in case I make important changes)?

Comment: You can of course stage your change for commit with `git add myfile.js`, in which case it will show up in the other part of `git status` until you change it again.  I'm assuming you don't like this answer though?

Comment: I don't want to include it in this commit, maybe in a future one

Comment: Why not just commit those changes and be done with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is no.

Git status is comparing three things:  Your working tree, the index, and HEAD.  If you want your working tree to differ from HEAD, then there are three possibilities:  the index can be the same as the working tree (changes staged for commit), the index can be the same as HEAD (changes not staged for commit), or the index can be neither (in which case you have some changes that are staged for commit and some that aren't).

So I don't think what you want can be done, short of post-processing the output of git-status or temporarily manipulating HEAD to something that is never intended to be part of history.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find anything for `git status`, however for `git diff` you can use:

```
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w --ignore-blank-lines
```

Hope it helps.